# Program that count how many white spaces are between words

Tags: c

I want to make a program in C that count how many white spaces are between words.
This is the code, but I can't solve the error that occurred.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){
    char str[200];
    int a[200];
    int i, z, c;
    int WordsCount = 0;
    puts("Give String");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(str);

    for (int i=0; str[i]!= '\0'; i++){
       
        if (str[i] == ' '){
            WordsCount++;
            int count = 0;
            for (z=i; str[z]!=' '; z++ ){
                count++;
            }

            i = z;
            a[WordsCount-1] = count;
        }
    }
    for (int c=0; c<WordsCount; c++){
        printf("%d", a[c]);
    }



}
```

Comment: Never use `gets`.

Comment: "... the error that occurred" -- Care to tell us which error occurred? Do you get an unexpected answer? Does the program crash?

Comment: Use a debugger to actually debug the problem. Surely it will show you a problem with this line: `int WordsCount = 0;`. That line is wrong for multiple reasons - it zeroes out the variable each loop and perhaps even worse, it is a different variable to the `int WordsCount;` declared earlier which is the one that is actually used at the end.

Comment: Why increment `WordsCount` before you need to, only to have to subtract 1 later? Also, can you think of a way to eliminate the loop with `z`? Do you really need `count`?

Answer (score 0):

At least one problem:

**`str[z]!=' '` is always false**

When `str[i] == ' '` is true, `z=i; str[z]!=' '` is false.

Check the next character.

```
    if (str[i] == ' '){
        WordsCount++;
        //int count = 0;
        int count = 1;
        //for (z=i; str[z]!=' '; z++ ){
        for (z=i; str[z+1]!=' ' && str[z+1]!='\0'; z++ ){
            count++;
        }

        i = z;
        a[WordsCount-1] = count;
    }
```